# Are there limitations for nesting in Javascript? ("Error 21: Undefined is not an object" in Illustrator)

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe

I'm using javascript with Adobe Illustrator CC 2015, and I'm trying to organize information about the artboards.

```
var myArt = {

types : { 
    type: "",
    board : {
        name : "",
        refNum : 0,
        chk : {}
    }
}
}; 

//initialize
myArt.types = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

for (i=0; i<myArt.types.length; i++) {
    myArt.types[i].board = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
        for (j=0; j<myArt.types[0].board.length; j++) {
            myArt.types[i].board[j].name = "";
        }
};
```

I get `Error 21: Undefined is not an object` for the 2nd for loop.

As far as I can tell, what works for "types" should work for "board." The only difference I can see is that board is nested one level deeper. So I guess I'm wondering if there's some kind of limitation on nesting, or if there is some other problem that I'm not catching.

[image: A picture of the code with error message.]

Comment: myArt.types[i].board makes no sense, why does an number have a property?

Comment: When you do: `myArt.types = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];` you completely overwrite the `types` object and replace it with an array. Got beat to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your overriding myArt.types with an array of numbers. So in your second iteration when you are trying to do `myArt.types[0].board.length` you are actually calling `0.board.length,1.board.length`, but `0.board` is undefined. It looks like you are mixing up objects and arrays in javascript. Objects do not by default have a length property.

This is the data structure your loop is implying:

```
var myArt = {
    types: [{
            type: "",
            board: [{name: "",refNum: 0,chk: {}}]
        }]
};
```